# Crossing out a literals text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a literal that shows a number, say `4.00`. What I would like, is to format it with strike-through (like when you scratch something because it is wrong). I am doing this because I need to update it to a new price but keeping the old price visible:

```
old 16.00 (strike-through)  new 14.95 (normal).
```

This is what I have, but not sure how to implement it. It is possible?

```
 string myPrice = "16.00";
 litMyPrice.Text = myPrice.ToString("c")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use a `asp:Label` instead, which generates a `<span>` tag to be able to style it:

```
litMyPrice.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration: line-through;");
```

or

Make a CSS class and change the `CssClass` property, I recommend this approach.  Mixing markup and CSS or even .NET generated styles can cause you pain down the road.

```
.strikethrough {text-decoration: line-through;}

litMyPrice.CssClass = "strikethrough";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
litMyPrice.Text = String.Format("<del>{0}</del>", myPrice.ToString("c"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<del>16.00</del>
```

<del>15.00</del> now 16.00

Answer (score 0):

Assign a CssClass to the literal and style it with text-decoration:line-through.

Comment: Literal doesn't support CssClass, it's only text, it doesn't render a container.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that litMyPrice is a control on your UI. If its is an asp label, you should be able to set

```
<asp:Label ... Font-Strikeout="true" />
```